# Number of outcomes in permutation invariant Multinomial Distributions

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-distribution

I have a dice with $K$ many outcomes. I am rolling this dice $n$ times. Assume $k_i$ denotes number of times class $i = 1,\ldots,K$ appears in $n$ many rolls. I am wondering, in how many different ways we can assign the $k_i$ values. Here, the order does **not** matter.

For example, let $n=3$ and $K=2$. We have four different outcomes:

- $k_1 = 3, k_2 = 0$
- $k_1 = 0, k_2 = 3$
- $k_1 = 2, k_1 = 1$
- $k_1 = 1, k_2 = 2$

So in this small example, there are $4$ different ways to assign $k_1,k_2$ values.

I think the problem is equivalent to the number of solutions to the following system:
$$k_1 + k_2 + \ldots k_K = n \\
k_i \geq 0, \text{and integer for }, i=1,\ldots,K  $$

So the solution is roughly:
$$\underbrace{{K}\choose{1}}_{\text{one takes $n$, others $0$}} + \underbrace{{K\choose{1}}}_{\text{one takes $n-1$}}\underbrace{{K-1\choose1}}_{\text{one takes $1$}} + 
\underbrace{{K\choose{1}}}_{\text{one takes $n-2$}}\left[ \underbrace{K-1\choose 1}_{\text{one takes $2$}}  \underbrace{+}_{\text{or}} \underbrace{K-1\choose 2}_{\text{two take $1$}}  \right] + \ldots
 $$
Is there a closed-form answer to this sum?

Comment: For example, it is said in the following link that if permutation is important then there are $K^n$ different outcomes. But here I don't really care about permutations:
https://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/multinomial.pdf

Comment: @user no, why is that?

Comment: @user because n=2

Comment: @user I edited something else, not what you suggested. Permutation does not matter of $k_1=  1, k_2=2$. So I don't care if I have $class 1, class 2$ or $class 2, class1$ in given order.

Comment: @user I think you are confused. But most probably my bad formatting made you be confused. What I say is, if you have Heads and Tails, and if you toss coin two times, having H-T or T-H does not matter, since each class appears once. But H-H and T-T are two different cases, since each class appears twice.

Comment: Ok I see now, what you mean. I retreat my comments.

Comment: @user thanks for your advice, I clarified the question with a new edit.

Comment: The solution of your problem is $\binom{n+K-1}{n}$.

Comment: @user thanks for that. Is there any source for this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that the problem is equivalent to finding the number of non-negative integer solutions to 
$$k_1 + k_2 + \ldots k_K = n \\
k_i \in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0},\;  i=1,\ldots,K  $$
is correct.

The problem is very well-known and its solution 
$$
\binom{n+K-1}n
$$
can be easily found by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Irrelevant question: can we say this is roughly polynomially many outcomes?

Comment: If one fixes $n$ or $K$ the expression is a polynomial wrt. to the other variable.